# how to use observables, async/await and subscribe in angular correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, promise, observable

I have a properties json file in location `assets/constants/props.json`. In the json file I have one key names `someValue` and its value is `abc`.

The json file looks like this:

[image]

I have a service file `constants.service.ts` and the 2 methods in it:

```
  public getJson(url : string) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }

  public someValue() : string {
    return this.getJson("assets/constants/props.json").subscribe(async (data: any) => {
      return await data.someValue;
    });
  }
```

And also in one of my components I use this value:

```
  private someValue! : string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someValue = this.server.someValue();
  }
```

In this way I get: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'string'.` error.

I have tried many ways and none of them worked:

1. make `someValue()` method returns `Promise<string>`
2. make `ngOnInit()` async method and use `await` in it
3. using `unsubsribe`, `toPromise()`, `toString()`...

And much more...

Every solution gave me a different error message, or gave me a wrong value `[object object]` instead of "abc".

I have tried all the possible options, and I can't get the result I expect.

My question is how to use `observables`, `async`, `await`, `subscribe` correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can directly convert either an `Observable<string>` *or* a `Promise<string>` into a `string`, because it makes no sense semantically.

Both Observables and Promises represent values that are not available yet but may be provided *at some point in the future*. Because all JavaScript I/O APIs I am aware of are designed *non-blocking*, you can't let your process sit around , wait and do nothing (i.e. *block*) until an I/O operation completes.

Instead, you register a callback function that will get invoked at a later point in time when a value is available. This is what `subscribe` in RxJS or `then` in Promises is for.

The `async` and `await` keywords are just syntax sugar for creating Promises and registering callbaks on them, respectively. Under the hood, *async* it just transforms the code that follows it into as callback function and registers it at a Promise. So in your example, it does nothing useful at all.

There are several ways you can get a value from an Observable.

Here's the simplest:

```js
ngOnOnit() {
  this.server.someValue().subscribe(value => this.someValue = value);
}
```

But this is a bit unwieldy, and there are some caveats with that, such as [potential memory leaks](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-avoid-memory-leaks-when-subscribing-to-rxjs-observables-in-angular-components).

There is a better way: Just let Angular deal with it, using [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). Just expose the `Observable` directly to the template and let Angular subscribe to it:

```js
someValue$: Observable<string>; // The "$" sign is just naming convention to tell Observables and plain values apart

ngOnInit() {
  this.someValue$ = this.server.someValue();
}
```

```html
<p>Your value: {{someValue$ | async}}</p>
```

As a sidenote, all of this will hopefully get much easier with Angular 16 when it gets support for [Signals](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-signals-everything-you-need-to-know-2b7g).

Comment: but if I use your idea of `this.server.someValue().subscribe(value => this.someValue = value);` and I write `alert(this.someValue)` after the previous line, I get `undefined`, unless I am waiting a few miliseconds and than it works. How can I wait until the value is actually loaded, and then do the alert. Why `await` won't work?

Comment: await works on Promise, and Observable is not a Promise. You can convert an Observable to Promise e.g. using [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) and then await on it.

Comment: And of course the value isn't available right away, because you are dealing with async I/O. That's what I was trying to explain all along, I honestly don't know how to make it any clearer.

Comment: Also I still recommend AsyncPipe over lastValueFrom + await.